# Wordpress Pagination Button working in desktop but not working in mobile or small screen

Tags: wordpress

I am making a blog site.
It has next button for every image using page break.
The next button is working in desktop perfectly but its not working in mobile.

```
$args = array(
    'before'           => '<center><p style="float:none;">' . __( '<span 
     style="margin-top:7px;font-size:18pt;">Page '.$page.'-
     '.$numpages.'</span>' ),
    'after'            => '</p></center>',
    'link_before'      => '',
    'link_after'       => '',
    'next_or_number'   => 'next', //change into number for numeric 
                          pagination
    'separator'        => ' ',
    'nextpagelink'     => __( '<button style="cursor:pointer;color:white; 
                                        background:#ff8000; border-
                                radius:40px;height:50px;width:250px;font-
                                size:15pt" class="btn"><span style>Next 
                             </span><span class="dashicons dashicons-arrow-right-alt2"></span></button>' ),
    'previouspagelink' => __(''),
    'pagelink'         => '%',
    'echo'             => 3
);
wp_link_pages( $args );
```

This works perfectly in desktop but does not respond in mobile

Answer (score 0):

Try changning button to an anchor with the same styling, here's your updated code:

```
$args = array(
    'before'           => '<center><p style="float:none;">' . __( '<span 
     style="margin-top:7px;font-size:18pt;">Page '.$page.'-
     '.$numpages.'</span>' ),
    'after'            => '</p></center>',
    'link_before'      => '',
    'link_after'       => '',
    'next_or_number'   => 'next', //change into number for numeric pagination
    'separator'        => ' ',
    'nextpagelink'     => __( '<span style="cursor:pointer;color:white; 
                                        background:#ff8000; border-
                                radius:40px;height:50px;width:250px;font-
                                size:15pt" class="btn">Next 
                             </span><span class="dashicons dashicons-arrow-right-alt2"></span>' ),
    'previouspagelink' => __(''),
    'pagelink'         => '%',
    'echo'             => 3
);
wp_link_pages( $args );
```

Comment: I've updated the answer, try now. Anchor shouldn't be in `nextpagelink`.